# how to find the latest folder in unix from windows?

Tags: windows, unix, ftp, file-transfer

I have a path in unix `/aaa/trial/<xxx>`.

means it has

```
/aaa/trial/123
/aaa/trial/124
/aaa/trial/125
```

`<xxx>` is a folder which will change for each extract produced and it is an increasing integer number.

I want to find the recent `xxx` folder

Comment: How are you looking at the unix files from windows? FTP (from tags)?

Comment: "Most recent" or "highest number"?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to `ls | sort | tail -1`.

Comment: I need to get the folder name from the windows machine

Comment: Ask Cygwin to be installed. Nowadays installs itself very easily, quick and straightforward. Leverage Microsoft OS!

Answer (score 0):

`DIR /OG /O-D /B` - the most recent folder will be listed first.